# How to unit test a function that uses window.localStorage in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, local-storage

How can I unit test a function that uses window.localStorage. Here are the two functions for checking and creating localStorage variable:

```
//  checks if Initial localStorage variable is true
//  returns boolean 
var isInitial = function() { 

    var doc = window.localStorage.getItem("Initial");
    console.log("intial: " + doc);
    if(doc !== "true"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }  
}; 

// create InitialSync localStorage item and sets it to true
// void
var createInitial = function() { 
    console.log("creating Initial");
    window.localStorage.setItem("Initial","true")   
};
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: reworded the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I unit tested this:

```
describe('isInitial function', function() {

    // clear localStorage before each spec
    beforeEach(function() {
        window.localStorage.clear(); 
    })  

    // isInitial should return true because 
    // there is no localStorage variable set
    it('should return true', function() {  
        var initial = SyncService.isInitial();
        expect(initial).toBe(true);   
    });  

    // after creating the Initial variable using createInitial()
    // we can test both functions
    it('should call createInitial and isInitial should be true', function() {
        SyncService.createInitial();
        var initial = SyncService.isInitial();
        console.log("initial: " + initial); 
        expect(initial).toBe(false);   
    });   

});
```